# loginページが出てこない

Tags: python, django

お疲れ様です。現在、アプリ開発をしている学生です。アプリ開発をしている中でどうしても躓いているところがあるので質問いたしました。

以下のviews.pyコードを打ち、`python manage.py runserver` と打つとloginページが出てくるはずなのですが、実際は真っ白なページが出てきてしまいます。何故なのでしょうか。

views.pyのコード

```
# coding:utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import redirect

# Create your views here.

def signupfunc(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username2 = request.POST['username']
        password2 = request.POST['password']
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username2)
            return render(request, 'signup.html', {'error':'このユーザーは登録されています'})
        except:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username2, '', password2)
            return render(request, 'signup.html', {'some':100})
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'some':100})

def loginfunc(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username2 = request.POST['username']
        password2 = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username2, password=password2)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('signup')   
        else:
            return redirect('signup')
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Comment: 質問の編集時、ソースコードの部分のみ選択して `{}` をクリックすると見やすく整形されるので、次回から試してみてください。 / 学生という自己紹介は質問に毎回含めるよりも、プロフィールページを活用しましょう。

Comment: コマンドプロンプトで　"python manage.py runserver"と打つと、Pythonでファイル"manage.py"に書かれているコードが実行され、runserverがその際の引数になります。

質問には、ファイル manage.py の説明もコードもありませんし、 views.pyのコードがどう関係しているのかも不明です。
views.pyのコードには関数の定義しかないので、"python views.py"とコマンドプロンプトで打っても何も起きないでしょうし。

落ち着いて、どのようなプログラムを書いて、どのように実行し、それで何が起きて、それが期待するものとどう違ったのかを、質問に追加してください。